Converting Raw Rails Select_all result row into multiple Model objects
I am needing to improve performance on a set of code that for a Vehicle and Owners tables, returns the following:
[ vehicles (list of vehicle objects), vehicles_to_owner (hashmap of vehicle.id -> owner instance) ]
It currently gets this information through multiple queries and we are dealing with massive amounts of data and this query is one of the most-called queries in our application (it's not vehicles/owners, but obfuscating).
I am instead creating a custom sql query, that I am considering using execute to get the raw results
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(select vehicle.*, owner.*
from vehicle 
join owner on vehicle.owner_id = owner.id)

Which I then want to do something similar to:
vehicleList = []
vehicleToOwnerMap = {}

results.map(|row|
vehicle = vehicle.new(row.vehicle.*)
owner = owner.new(row.author.*)

vehicleList.put(vehicle)
vehicleToOwnerMap.put(vehicle.id, owner)
)

What is the best way to instantiate a model object using a raw database result? Trying to let the database handle the complex operations and then just loop through the result set and build the final [ list, map] object during the single iteration and return that.

Based on your obfuscation it is extremely unclear what the intent or issue is given the basic ability to Vehicle.eager_load(:owners)

Just trying to keep down the iterations on the data. Instead of 2 separate queries then iterating through them to build the list and hashmap objects, wanted to do a single query and build them both during a single iteration. Trying to improve performance on the millisecond level

Right Vehicle.eager_load(:owners) is one large query and all the data is loaded. It will be a list of Vehicle objects with their associated Owner objects already pre-populated. Your entire desired code would be Vehicle.eager_load(:owners).map {|v| [v, {v.id => v.owners}]} but even that seems unnecessary
